# How to shrink the size of transferred images with wcf ria service?

Tags: c#, silverlight

I have a listbox to display photos retrieved from database by using wcf ria service in a silverlight project. The data loading time is long. The raw size of the photos are large byte[],but I only want to display a small image(icon) in the listbox. Is there a way that I can reduce the resolution of the photos before transfer to the client to reduce the data transfer size?

Thanks,

Wei

Comment: What do you mean? I am using wcf ria service to query out the records with byte[] data and binding it to the listbox. Thanks

Comment: I mean where do these byte arrays come from, are they stored in a database, stored on the filesystem?

Comment: If you have control over how it's stored, you should have control over the actual bytes you're sending.  If you use in Michael's answer, you would transfer the resized image's bytes instead of what's stored in the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this product http://imageresizing.net/.

It can resize your images to any size and keep the result cached to improve the speed of subsequent requests. It also is implemented in a very efficient way to allow for a better throughput of your IIS.

Comment: Are you sure this product can be used for Silverlight application with WCF RIA Service? And my images are stored in Database. Thanks,

Comment: Well, the product is pretty extensible, we're using it ourselves. It can definitely convert images if you supply it as byte arrays. But if you want performance, your best bet is to avoid going through full WCF stack and that's what that guy means when he says on the web site that he has fine tuned performance. You can return just a URL from your WCF call and then use WebClient or HttpWebRequest to get the data from the url (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc197953(v=VS.95).aspx)

Comment: Also, here's the link to Scott Hanselman's podcast with the guy where they discuss all the performance issues involved: http://www.hanselminutes.com/313/deep-inside-image-resizing-and-scaling-with-aspnet-and-iis-with-imageresizingnet-author-na